# CakePHP Bake from different templates when using prefix

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake, cake-bake

When I currently use `./cake.bat bake template Genres` or `./cake.bat bake template Genres --prefix admin`, then the templates are used from these locations:

```
cakephp\bake\src\Template\Bake\Template\view.twig
cakephp\bake\src\Template\Bake\Template\index.twig
cakephp\bake\src\Template\Bake\Template\add.twig
cakephp\bake\src\Template\Bake\Template\edit.twig
```

I want to different versions of all these templates when I bake with the admin prefix. I tried [creating a Bake Theme](https://book.cakephp.org/4.0/en/bake/development.html#creating-a-bake-theme).

- I ran `./cake.bat bake plugin AdminTheme`
- Then I placed the desired template files in `plugins/AdminTheme/templates/Bake/Template/`.
- Ran `./cake.bat bake template Genres --theme AdminTheme`
- Got `Error: "AdminTheme" is not a valid value for --theme. Please use one of "Bake, Migrations, WyriHaximus/TwigView"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixes won't affect the template source, the path is pretty much hardcoded in **[`\Bake\Shell\Task\TemplateTask::getContent()`](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/1.11.2/src/Shell/Task/TemplateTask.php#L386)**. One way to uses different templates is to bake each action separately, and use the `action` argument, and optionally the `alias` argument to use the default name for the output, something along the lines of this:

```sh
bin\cake bake template Genres admin_index index --prefix Admin
```

That would use the `Template/admin_index.ctp|twig` file, and write to `Template/Admin/Genres/index.ctp`.

As for your bake theme, the template folder structure in your theme plugin has to be:

```
AdminTheme/src/Template/Bake/Template/
```

not

```
AdminTheme/templates/Bake/Template/
```

Also make sure that your plugin is actually being loaded, ie check that `$this->addPlugin('AdminTheme');` exists in your `Application` class' `bootstrap()` method, or for earlier versions `Plugin::load('AdminTheme');` in your `config/bootstrap.php` file.

See also **[Bake Cookbook > Extending Bake > Creating a Bake Theme](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1.x/en/development.html#creating-a-bake-theme)**

Comment: Both of your methods worked. I was seeing the documentation for the 4.0 version while using the 3.0 version. Thanks!